# Loquendo Olga python

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx3

Как найти токен TTS Loquendo Olga для озывучивания через модуль pyttsx3?

Например, это для выбора голоса Irina в Windows:

```py
ru_voice_id = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_RU-RU_IRINA_11.0"
```

А мне нужна такая же строка, но для Loquendo Olga

Comment: открой regedit и посмотри путь к папке

Comment: Путь к какой папке? В этом то и вопрос

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Loquendo\LTTS7
Здесь у меня ничего нет

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\` - где искать токен? в папке с токенами естественно!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[нужно вставить порядковой номер Ольги, токена].id)
engine.say(text)
engine.runAndWait.()
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно посмотреть какие языки доступны.
Как добавить новые еще не придумал :)

> import pyttsx3 engine = pyttsx3.init() voices =
> engine.getProperty('voices') for voice in voices:
> print('==============')
> print(f'Имя: {voice.name}')
> print(f'ID: {voice.id}')
> print(f'Язык: {voice.languages}')
> print(f'Пол: {voice.gender}')
> print(f'Возраст: {voice.age}') engine.runAndWait()

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: каким образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос? изложите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вашего ответа, нажав [edit]